# making java application as a windows service

Tags: java, mysql, windows-services

My java application uses swings and makes a connection to the MySQL database. I want to run this application as a windows service which should start immediately at the logon of any user.

I think Java Service Wrapper is useful only for console applications.So kindly suggest me a suitable method.
Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to have apps with user interfaces as services.  Services can start at boot, and if they pop up a panel, they can hang the service waiting for user input with no user to provide any input.  Split out the UI from the service code if you want to run the code as a service.  Or like Andy mentioned, place the exe in the users startup group.

Comment: I actually want my system not to proceed (or hang) if no user has entered details into the application. Once the user has entered data then only he can proceed.

Comment: @Kritika - The problem is the UI will not be displayed to the user. It will be hidden, so there is no way for the user to access it.  If you want user interaction, you will want to add it to the start group for the specified user, or all users if that is what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Windows service, [Exe4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html) makes this easy. It will wrap your Java application in an executable that supports options to install, start, stop and remove it from Windows services.

If you want to start a user interface at the start of a user's logon, you can put the application into the Startup group.

Comment: thanks for help but if i put the application in the startup group then the user would be able to access other system resources like internet explorer but i want that the user must first views my java application then only he is allowed to access the other resources.

Comment: As i am new to this i want to ask that if i make an exe file then would it be able to connect to the MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

The binaries (e.g. tomcat6.exe, and tomcat6w.exe) that are included with Apache Tomcat can be used to turn a java application into a service. Here's a link to the documentation, which includes instructions for installing your app as a service, etc.: [Tomcat as a Windows service](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://kenai.com/projects/winsw works great, and allows easy logging of System.out and System.err.

Used in Glassfish v3.